# Why JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE vs EXIT_ON_CLOSE?

Tags: java, swing, methods

In nearly all code examples I've come across, the parameter for the method `setDefaultCloseOperation` in classes derived from `JFrame` is some constant such as `JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE.` In this case, since `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` is a constant of `JFrame`, it can be accessed directly, and doesn't need a getter method to access it. Why do we still prefix it with the superclass name `JFrame`? Any Swing class is a subclass of `JFrame`, and would inherit the `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` constant, so why not just write out the method invocation as `setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE)`
instead of `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)`?

Is the explicit superclass name really necessary?

Comment: 1) Don't extend `JFrame`, just use an instance as we can in 99.9% of cases. 2) A more interesting question would then be "`JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE` vs `JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE`", where I'd be shouting out the case for the latter.

Answer (score 6):

`EXIT_ON_CLOSE` is a static member of the JFrame class, meaning it's the same across all instances of the JFrame class.

**Why specify the class?**

Because what if you have an `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` variable in a child class? That variable would be used instead. Thus, to obtain the correct int value (in this case) of the static variable, you must say which class the variable is defined in.

It's similar to the reason you say `this.variable` when addressing a class variable for an instance of a class. Here, we're just saying the class name `JFrame` instead of `this` because the variable is the same across all instances.